# How to create a better expandable/collapse div?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working on an image grid feature in which images are being displayed. I'm facing issue regarding creating an expandable/collapsable div.

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="Display('images')">
   <section class="image-grid" *ngFor="let item of items$|async">
      <div class="image__cell is-collapsed">
         <div class="image--basic">
            <img (click)="expandImage()" class="basic__img" src="{{item.link}}">
         </div>
         <div class="image--expand" [ngClass]="{'image--expand': !_expand}">
            <a class="expand__close"></a>
            <img class="image--large" src="{{item.link}}">
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
 </div>
```

.ts file

```
private _maxHeight: string;
private _marginBottom: string;
private _expand: boolean = false;

expandImage() {
  this._expand = !this._expand;
  this._maxHeight = '500px';
  this._marginBottom = '10px';
}
```

CSS

```
.image-grid {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.image__cell {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.basic__img {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image__cell.is-collapsed {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.6%;
}

.image__cell.is-collapsed .image--basic {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image--expand {
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #222;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .3s ease-in-out,margin-bottom .1s .2s;
}

.expand__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.expand__close:before {
  content: '×';
}

.expand__close:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.image--large {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The code above creates an expandable div. But the problem is whenever, I click on any one image, the div gets expanded in each row. I'm trying to create similar to this: [Recreating image-viewer](https://www.sitepoint.com/recreating-google-images-search-layout-css/). It would be great if someone can help me out in this. Thanks. :)

Comment: You have only one _expand state variable for all images. You need to move it into an item, so each item will have it's own _expand state.

Comment: @hiper2d how should I achieve it? It would be great if you can help me with a solution. Thanks for giving time to my question. :)

Comment: I had similar problem, so as a temporary solution was to add this `_expand: = false;` property to the objects itself.

Comment: @J.D. I'm new to this. It would be great if you can provide solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing here,

Pass clicked key to this functions `(click)="expandImage(item.$key)"` 
and in your code

```
expandImage(key) {
this._expand = !this._expand;
this.clickedItem = key;
this._maxHeight = '500px';
this._marginBottom = '10px';
}
```

and in your template

```
<div class="image--expand" *ngIf="clickedItem == item.$key" [ngClass]="{'image--expand': !_expand}">
     <a class="expand__close"></a>
     <img class="image--large" src="{{item.link}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, when I click on one image, the expandable action is being performed for all the images. It should only expand for 1 image on which it has been clicked. :)

Comment: each ngFor generates a unique key, you get the current clicked key in to a variable and check  to show the div using ngIf.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm new to this and still not able to implement it perfectly. The solution is not working. :/

Comment: you can also add multiple classes using `[ngClass]`, like `[ngClass]="{'image--expand': !_expand, 'image--hide': clickedItem == item.$key}`

Comment: Thanks! But this is new I heard from your side `ngFor` generates unique keys. :)

Comment: where you getting those async data?, i am using firebase and i have it.